# Spring boot not ignoring data.sql during tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-boot-test

I want my spring boot repository tests to not use the `data.sql` file defined in the `src/main/resources` when executing tests. I'm running spring boot version `3.0.1`

Currently I have an `application.yaml` file defined in `src/main/resources` with the following:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:productdb
    username: sa
    password: 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    # Disable hibernate auto schema creation
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
  # Makes console log output colourful
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS

server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: "/product-service"
```

and I have `data.sql` file that has 3 insert statements, just so there is some sample data when I start up the application:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, PRICE, STOCK_STATUS, STOCK_COUNT) VALUES ('PRODUCT 1', 2000, 'AVAILABLE', 100);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, PRICE, STOCK_STATUS, STOCK_COUNT) VALUES ('PRODUCT 2', 500.50, 'AVAILABLE', 47);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, PRICE, STOCK_STATUS, STOCK_COUNT) VALUES ('PRODUCT 3', 140.56, 'OUT_OF_STOCK', 0);
```

I also have a `schema.sql` file in `src/main/resources`:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   product_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
   stock_status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   stock_count INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

I have a repository test class that uses `@DataJpaTest` to bootstrap the repository and entity classes defined liked so:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ProductRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    public void should_findAllProducts() {
        final Product p = new Product();
        p.setName("Test");
        p.setPrice(BigDecimal.TEN);
        p.setStockCount(100);
        p.setStockStatus(StockStatus.AVAILABLE);
        testEntityManager.persist(p);
        assertEquals(1, this.productRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

Finally, I have an `application-test.yaml` file in `src/main/resources`, which I added, as I believed it was supposed to stop spring from loading the `data.sql` file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: never
```

However, this does not work as expected, and the test fails with an assertion error

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :4
```

telling me that it is still loading the `data.sql` file. This is not the expected behaviour as far as I'm aware, but appears to be the case. I originally did not have the profile `test`, and simply just had the same `application-test.yaml` but called `application.yaml` in `src/main/resources`. But I realised that his then meant that the tests would not pick up the properties present in the main properties file (since they had the same name), and therefore hiberante would auto create the schema based on how it is defined in the java class, and not use the schema.sql file, which is not what I want.

What I want essentially, is for the tests to use the `schema.sql` file to create the schema, but not use the `data.sql` for injecting data. I want the data that is inserted to be controlled by the tests.

Can someone help me understand why adding the property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never` does not resolve the problem? Or perhaps suggest an alternative way to achieve the same result?

**EDIT:**

After some additional research I've found that `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` was deprecated, but the alternative solution I'm seeing of `spring.sql.init.mode=never` does not work for me, as that stops the tests using the `schema.sql` file, which I *don't* want

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways addressing your requirement, below are approaches

By using [@Sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html) annotation, spring also provides the @Sql annotation a declarative way to initialize and populate our test schema. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql#sqlannotation)

```
@Sql({"/schema.sql"})
public class ProductRepositoryTest {
   //This will execute only schema.sql

}
```

Note : In this approach you have to disable the script-based initialization, setting `spring.sql.init.mode=never`

In the second approach you can enable the `script-based initialization` and just clean up the table before every test case execution using `@BeforeEach`.

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ProductRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        productRepository.deleteAll();
     }

    @Test
    public void should_findAllProducts() {
         final Product p = new Product();
         p.setName("Test");
         p.setPrice(BigDecimal.TEN);
         p.setStockCount(100);
         p.setStockStatus(StockStatus.AVAILABLE);
         testEntityManager.persist(p);
         assertEquals(1, this.productRepository.findAll().size());
     }
  }
```

In the third approach you can simply call the `productRepository.deleteAll()` method inside the test case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had thought of just deleting the data in a setup step before the tests, but it just didn't seem like it was the "spring way" to do it. I presumed there would be something clever I was missing to simply stop it using the data.sql file. I have tried your approach with the `@Sql` annotation, but this still causes 2 of my 3 tests to fail, saying the table already exists. I'm presuming it is trying to execute the `schema.sql` file before each test, is that the expected behaviour of the annotation? I didn't think it was